# Couln't resolve host name error using curl in Tizen wearable native application

Tags: curl, permissions, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

Hi so I'm new to Tizen SDK and developing watch application. I encountered an error while using curl to post/get. Below is the code I'm using, anyone can help?

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, TAG, "curl start");

/* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

/* get a curl handle */
curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, TAG, "curl init");
  /* Set CURL parameters */
    /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
    just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
    data. */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
    /* Now specify the POST data */
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "w=4&project=curl");

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, TAG, "curl_easy_perform() Failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));
    else{
        dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, TAG, "curl_easy_perform() Success");

    }

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
else{
    dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, TAG, "curl failed");
}
      curl_global_cleanup();
```

EDIT:
the error is "Unable to resolve host name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try code like this with API privilege:

```
    <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/network.get</privilege>
    <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/internet</privilege>
```

This code simply requests for a data and receive that data . Here

```
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, "data", "Response Data");
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, "data", chunk.memory);
```

are used to view the received data.

Calling Function:

```
Eina_Bool sendRequest(void *data EINA_UNUSED) {
CURL *curl;
CURLcode curl_err;
chunk.memory = malloc(1);
chunk.size = 0;
curl = curl_easy_init();
connection_h connection;
int conn_err;
conn_err = connection_create(&connection);
if (conn_err != CONNECTION_ERROR_NONE) {
    /* Error handling */
    return false;
}
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
        "http://apidev.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/28143.json?language=en&apikey=hoArfRosT1215");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
/* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void * )&chunk);
curl_err = curl_easy_perform(curl);
if (curl_err != CURLE_OK) {
    /* Error handling */
    return false;
}
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, "data", "Response Data");
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, "data", chunk.memory);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
free(chunk.memory);
connection_destroy(connection);
return EINA_TRUE;}
```

Log Output:

[image]

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: just want to ask what is the parameter *data for?

Comment: It seems i lack the privilage. I thought adding features was enough. Thanks now im off to parsing. Thank you!